# How to set a DateTime variable in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, datetime

SQL Server 2008 is not doing what I expected with `DateTime`. It doesn't let me set `DateTime` variables, no matter what date format I use.

When I execute:

```
DECLARE @Test AS DATETIME
SET @Test = 2011-02-15
PRINT @Test
```

I get an output of:

```
Jun 18 1905 12:00AM
```

I've checked all of the regional settings that I can find & it all appears okay. I've also tried setting the `DateTime` to various literal alternatives, such as '15/02/2011', '2011-02-15 00:00:00', etc.

Answer (score 47):

You need to enclose the date time value in quotes:

```
DECLARE @Test AS DATETIME 

SET @Test = '2011-02-15'

PRINT @Test
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @DaveRead.   Did you test this? doesnt seem to be doing whats needed.

Answer (score 18):

First of all - use single quotes around your date literals!

Second of all, I would strongly recommend always using the ISO-8601 date format - this works regardless of what your locale, regional or language settings are on your SQL Server.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is either:

- `YYYYMMDD` for dates only (e.g. `20110825` for the 25th of August, 2011)
- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and time (e.g. `2011-08-25T14:15:00` for 25th of AUgust, 14:15/2:15pm in the afternoon)

Comment: ISO 8601 includes dashes when the date is alone.

Comment: @AaronFranke: yes - the "full" ISO-8601 does - the **adapted** version for SQL Server must not have dashes when you want to convert this to a `DATETIME` datatype without errors. `DATETIME` is extremely picky (and illogical) that way.....

Comment: @AaronFranke: if your SQL Server's language is set to just about anything but US English, something like `CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-08-25')` will **FAIL** - whereas `CONVERT(DATETIME, '20110825')` works - **always** - regardless of language settings

Comment: Yes, but `CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-08-25', 120)` succeeds. You just need to specify the format and then CONVERT will be able to parse an ISO 8601 date directly.

Comment: @AaronFranke: ok - I usually use `CAST` which doesn't support formats to be specified. The adapted ISO-8601 format always works - no matter what settings you have. I'll pick that for my usage

Answer (score 7):

`2011-01-15` = `2011-16` = `1995`.  This is then being implicitly converted from an integer to a date, giving you the 1995th day, starting from 1st Jan 1900.

You need to use `SET @test = '2011-02-15'`

Answer (score 7):

Try using Select instead of Print

```
DECLARE @Test AS DATETIME 

SET @Test = '2011-02-15'

Select @Test
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to explain:

`2011-02-15` is being interpreted literally as a mathematical operation, to which the answer is `1994`.

This, then, is being interpreted as 1994 days since the origin of date (Jan 1st 1900).

1994 days = 5 years, 6 months, 18 days = June 18th 1905

So, if you don't want to to the calculation each time you want compare a date to a particular value use the standard: Compare the value of the `toString()` function of date object to the string like this :

```
set @TEST  ='2011-02-05'
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to make the format/style explicit and don't rely on interpretation based on local settings (which may vary among your clients infrastructure).

```sql
DECLARE @Test AS DATETIME
SET @Test = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-02-15 00:00:00', 120) -- yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
SELECT @Test
```

While there is a [plethora of styles](https://web.archive.org/web/20200729210252/http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/), you may want to remember few

- 126 (ISO 8601): yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.mmm)
- 120: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
- 112: yyyyMMdd

Note that the T in the ISO 8601 is actually the letter T and not a variable.

Comment: The link in your post is dead.

Comment: @AaronFranke thankfully archive.org has a copy I could link to, should be fixed now

Answer (score 2):

You Should Try This Way :

```
  DECLARE @TEST DATE
  SET @TEST =  '05/09/2013'
  PRINT @TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. I create new Date() and convert her in String .
 2. This string I set in insert.

 **Example:**  insert into newDate(date_create) VALUES (?)";

 ...
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(CREATE))
        ps.setString(1, getData());
        ps.executeUpdate();
  ...}

   private String getData() {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd hh:mm:ss");
     return  sdf.format(new java.util.Date());
    }

 **It is very important format** = "yyyy-M-dd hh:mm:ss"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CONVERT` function helps.Check this:

```
declare @erro_event_timestamp as Timestamp;
set @erro_event_timestamp = CONVERT(Timestamp,  '2020-07-06 05:19:44.380',  121);
```

The magic number 121 I found here: https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/func_sqlserver_convert.asp