# Datediff function in mySQL using variable and current date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the time remaining based on a target date. I have a target date of `July 4, 2022 10:00:00` and I want to subtract that from today's date.

I first did `SET @var_name = "July 4, 2022 10:00:00"`, followed by `SELECT datediff(now(),@var_name)` but it keeps returning a null value. Is there a way where I can have it display the number of days, hours and minutes remaining from the target date?

Comment: Format the date as YYYY-MM-DD `SELECT datediff(now(),'2022-06-04 10:00:00')`

Comment: what timezone is your target date?

Comment: There's a stackoverflow post about setting a datetime variable on sql server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188222/how-to-set-a-datetime-variable-in-sql-server-2008. You can check that out and see if it suits your question.

Comment: it's CST timezone

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

- format your string into the DATE format with [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

  ```
  STR_TO_DATE(@var_name, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s')
  ```
- get difference in seconds between dates with [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff):

  ```
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), STR_TO_DATE(...))
  ```
- transform seconds into time with [`SEC_TO_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time):

  ```
  SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(...))
  ```
- extract hours, minutes and seconds from time using [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

  ```
  DATE_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(...), '%H hours %i minutes %s seconds')
  ```
- extract days separately as an integer division between hours and 24:

  ```
  HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(...)) DIV 24
  ```

---

Check the full query followingly:

```
SET @var_name = "July 4, 2022 10:00:00";

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(
                TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
                              NOW(),
                              STR_TO_DATE(@var_name,
                                          '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s'))) AS seconds               )
SELECT CONCAT(HOUR(seconds) DIV 24,
              ' days ',
              DATE_FORMAT(seconds,
                          '%H hours %i minutes %s seconds'))
FROM cte
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2gejC2o6XoSVxNSMG2QVFa/0).